# Frequency limit of writing to shared memory?

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory, shared-memory

Single threaded application (C++) continuously locks, writes and unlocks shared memory - **four times a second** (the loop is programically set to run once a second and there are 4 writes in the loop and no reads).

> EnterCriticalSection(cs);
>     WriteToSharedMem();
>   LeaveCriticalSection(cs);

Another application (C) will access this shared memory once every few **minutes**.

Are there any problems with writing to shared memory at this rate?

Windows XP
C++

Comment: You cannot synchronize between processes with critical sections.  They can only synchronize between threads in the same process.  If you need to synchronize with another process, you need to use a Mutex, probably a named Mutex.

Comment: Or a semaphore, why does everyone love mutexes so much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this rate there definitely not! This is extremely slow, however I'm not sure Critical section is what you want to use, the way I remember it that only ensures thread safety, not cross-application safety, you should look for something else to lock shared memory. You have to use some [Inter-Process Communication (IPC)](http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html) mechanism to ensure atomic operations with shared memory.

Comment: Is a link to tldp really useful for a Windows question?

Comment: @kbyrd The mechanisms are the same regardless of platform, and I think they are explained there in a manner much easier to understand than the explanations on MSDN, additionally they're all on one page.

Answer (score 8):

The rate you give (four times a second) won't cause a problem, but [you can't use critical sections across processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You need a kernel level synchronization object like a [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Not at all.  You can get/release the lock thousands (or tens or hundreds of thousands) of times per second.  You could easily do a quick benchmark to see.

Comment: sounds like a I am way way under any implications of frequency issues.